# The switch case expression type 'String' must be a subtype of the switch expression type 'SelectFieldBloc<String, dynamic>'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, conditional-statements

I put a switch case for each of my dropdown values, its show the alert `The switch case expression type 'String' must be a subtype of the switch expression type 'SelectFieldBloc<String, dynamic>'.` so what can i do to change it into String, dynamic. This is my switch case

```
    switch(_formBloc){
      case 'Option 1': return Text("zero widget");
      case 1: return Text("one widget");
      case 2: return Text("two widget");
      case 3: return Text("three widget");
      case 4: return Text("three widget");
      case 5: return Text("three widget");
      default: return Text("default widget");
    }
```

and this is where i store the value of my drop down:

```
final filepicker2 = InputFieldBloc<PlatformFile?, Object>(initialValue: null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with bloc so I might be wrong, but I'm guessing you want to switch on the value and not the bloc. Also the numbers are `int` and not `String` so you might want to write `'1'` instead of `1`. So like:

```
switch(_formBloc.value){
  case 'Option 1': return Text("zero widget");
  case '1': return Text("one widget");
  case '2': return Text("two widget");
  case '3': return Text("three widget");
  case '4': return Text("three widget");
  case '5': return Text("three widget");
  default: return Text("default widget");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 switch(_formBloc){
      case 0: return Text("zero widget");
      case 1: return Text("one widget");
      case 2: return Text("two widget");
      case 3: return Text("three widget");
      case 4: return Text("three widget");
      case 5: return Text("three widget");
      default: return Text("default widget");
    }
```

prefer to use only one datatype in case